# How can I specify location of AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

I'm porting a module from Eclipse to Android Studio/Gradle, and need to specify the locations of my sources, resources, and manifest:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest {
            srcFile './AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src"]
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["resource"]
        }
    }
}
```

Android Studio/Gradle seems perfectly happy with my `java` and `resources` entries, but balks at my `manifest` entry:

```
No signature of method: build_b4wnchd9ct4a5qt388vbbtbpz.sourceSets() is applicable for argument types: (build_b4wnchd9ct4a5qt388vbbtbpz$_run_closure2) values: [build_b4wnchd9ct4a5qt388vbbtbpz$_run_closure2@35290d54]
```

All of my googling and searching SO suggests that this should have worked.

Arctic Fox, 2020.3.1. Not sure which version of Gradle came with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahh, figured it out. Leaving here in case someone else has the same question.

Add an `android.sourceSets.manifest.srcFile` entry to your module's `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest {
                srcFile './AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or simply:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile './AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

My biggest mistake was not putting the `sourceSets` directive inside the `android` directive.